# How to use Nuxt 3 gtag module composables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, gtag.js

So I use [nuxt-gtag](https://nuxt.com/modules/gtag#usegtag) module for my app and its setup in nuxt config is working fine.

```
modules:['nuxt-gtag'],
   gtag: {
   id: 'GTM-ID-HERE', // working as expected
},
```

But when I tried to use their composables gtag is returning an empty arrow func. I want to use the composables so I can pass dynamic google tag id

```
mounted() {
   const gtag = useGtag() 
      gtag('config', 'GTM-ID-HERE'); // not working for some reason
      console.log(" ~ file: Header.vue:260 ~ mounted ~ gtag:", gtag) // empty arrow func
},
```